# Is it possible to define a suggestion list in webview applications?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, textinput

When entering a string in a text type input element in a webview based app, a list of possible words is showed above the virtual keyboard.

In my application the user is not allowed to input arbitrary words, instead only words and phrases from a database are legal.

So, I want to set the list of words from my phonegap app and disable the automatic creation of this list.

Q: Is this possible to create the list - and how?

(This is a phonegap app and I am testing on android, but this might be a problem for webview / text input fields on different platforms)

**EDIT:**
Just found out (yes, I'm new to android development), that one can disable the suggestion list with: Settings / Language and Keyboard / Android keyboard / Show suggestions.

But of course, this setting should be made only for the app, from inside the app, without user interaction and not changing anything outside the app.

Any chance to get this done?

**EDIT 2:**
Instead of disabling the suggestion list I tried to use it.
The displayCompletions method of InputMethodManager sounded promising, so I tried the following code:

```
...
// data member
InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = null;
...

    ...
    // initialized
    mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    ...

public void showSuggestions(String[] words) {
    Log.d(TAG, "showSuggestions (in Java!): " + words.length);  // yes, this code is executed
    CompletionInfo[] completions = new CompletionInfo[words.length];
    for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        completions[i] = new CompletionInfo(i, i, words[i]);    // no idea, what the 2 extra integers mean
    }
    mInputMethodManager.displayCompletions(mView, completions);
}
```

The method is executed, whenever a new list is available (after the input has changed and the server has answered a request).

However, nothing has changed - the builtin mechanism is still doing its disadvantageous work.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are different variants of virtual keyboard(swype and others) there might be no list of possible words. So, I suppose there is no general solution for not showing this list.

There is a parameter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:editorExtras editorExtras which defines parameters passed to input method implementation, but I'm not sure how would you use it in PhoneGap application

**Edit:**

I suppose you can extend default input method and make it not to show suggestions
inputmethod reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html

> Providing Custom Software Keyboards
>
> If you are interested in developing your own software keyboards, we highly recommend the following references:
>
> IMEs are implemented as an Android service. Begin by reviewing the Android packages called android.inputmethodservice and android.view.inputmethod, which can be used to implement custom input methods.
>       The SoftKeyboard sample application in the Android SDK provides an implementation of a software keyboard.
>       The Android Developer technical articles on onscreen input methods and creating an input method.

found it here http://e-university.wisdomjobs.com/android/chapter-946-288/handling-advanced-user-input.html

Comment: I don't think a HTML input field in a webview can be configured with methods for the Android TextView widget. Second: I was not aware, that there might be other keyboards than the default one are installed. But configuring only the default soft keyboard should be ok.

Comment: sorry, I forgot that this is a text field in HTML page. So the only way is to validate/modify inputted text by yourself in JS

Comment: Halfway done. I've implemented a suggestion list in JS (the HTML5 datalist is not working with an - android only? - webview). But how can I disable the suggestion list provided by the default keyboard?

Comment: Implementing a new input service is too much for my app. Not only that I have to implement it, the service has to be installed and selected. This selection must be made by the user - manually, before using the app. This would affect - as far as I understand - not only my app, but all apps using text input.

Comment: well, this is what I meant it is too much overhead, even though you don't need to implement service, but just change behaviour of existing. If I'm right this will affect only your app

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like the auto complete in jQuery UI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Also, it's not too hard to whip this up yourself in JavaScript.

http://www.javascript-examples.com/autocomplete-demo/

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. Actually I've done this already. The remaining problem is, that the list of useless suggestions is still there, waisting valuable space on the screen and giving the user the wrong choices.